# Enable AWS RDS Auto Scaling via Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, aws-auto-scaling

I have RDS instances running in my AWS account created via a Cloudformation template. Recently there was a storage-full occurrence and as immediate remediation, I modified storage size from default 20 GB to 50 GB from the console.

Now I am considering modifying my CFN template so that RDS auto-scaling is enabled. But as I went through the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIOPS.StorageTypes.html#USER_PIOPS.Autoscaling), it says auto-scaling can be enabled through CLI, RDS API, and Console, and no mention about Cloudformation?

Is there any way to enable auto-scaling via Cloudformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not direct option for that, as explained in the following GitHub issue:

- [AWS::RDS::DBInstance (add Storage Auto Scaling)](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/72)

However, it seems that if you set `MaxAllocatedStorage`, the storage autoscaling will get enabled.

Comment: There is an open issue as well:
https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/430

Comment: I will try the MaxAllocatedStorage thing

Comment: Did not implement it yet coz I created CW alarm instead. But setting MaxAllocatedStorage will definitely work I know. So going to accept the answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69734205/aws-cloudformation-does-cloudwatch-alarm-for-rds-needs-iam-role/69734554?noredirect=1#comment123288156_69734554